# How to overwrite Python Jupyter display output

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I have created a small form with ipywidgets. The sample code can be run in Jupyter or Google colab.

Each time the form is filled and the button is clicked a row gets added to a dataframe. Subsequently the dataframe gets displayed.

My problem is that the output displays the new updated dataframe on top of the old one. What I want is that the new display output overwrites the old one. [See image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb6rp.png).

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, Label
from ipywidgets import Layout, Button, Box, FloatText, Textarea, Dropdown, Label, IntSlider
import time
import pandas as pd

#Create DF
df = df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Dropdown_column', 'Float_column'])
df

# Layout
form_item_layout = Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='row',
    justify_content='space-between',
)


button_item_layout = Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='row',
    justify_content='center',
    padding = '5%'
)

# Dropdown item

drop_down_input = 'Dropdown_input_1'

drop_down = widgets.Dropdown(options=[('Dropdown_input_1', 'Dropdown_input_1'), ('Dropdown_input_2','Dropdown_input_2'), ('Dropdown_input_3', 'Dropdown_input_3')])

def dropdown_handler(change):
    global drop_down_input
    print('\r','Dropdown: ' + str(change.new),end='')
    drop_down_input = change.new  
drop_down.observe(dropdown_handler, names='value')

# FloatText item

float_input = 0

FloatText = widgets.FloatText()

def IntText_handler(change):
    global float_input
    print('\r','Float text:' + str(change.new),end='')
    float_input = change.new 
FloatText.observe(IntText_handler, names='value')



# Button

button = widgets.Button(description='Add row to dataframe')
out = widgets.Output()
def on_button_clicked(b):
    global df
    button.description = 'Row added'
    time.sleep(1)
    with out:
      new_row = {'Dropdown_column': drop_down_input, 'Float_column': float_input}
      df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
      button.description = 'Add row to dataframe'
      display(df)
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

# Form items

form_items = [         
    Box([Label(value='Dropdown'),
         drop_down], layout=form_item_layout),
    Box([Label(value='FloatText'),
         FloatText], layout=form_item_layout),
    Box([Label(value=''), button],
        layout=button_item_layout),    
]

form = Box(form_items, layout=Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='column',
    border='solid 1px',
    align_items='stretch',
    width='30%',
    padding = '1%'
))
display(form)
display(out)
```

I have tried using the print() function in combination with '/r' and changing #button part of my code.
Change:

```
display(df)
```

to

```
print('\r',str(df), end='')
```

or

```
print(str(df), end='\r')
```

But this does not work either.

Does somebody have any idea what to do?

Comment: `Jupyter` is not `console/terminal` and code useful in `print` in console is useless in Jupyter. You should rather use some funciton to clear `widget` - maybe it has function `.clear()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r` works only for single line of normal text but `df` is not displayed as normal text (and it is not single line) but as HTML code.

You have to use `out.clear_output()` to remove previous content.

```
   with out:
      new_row = {'Dropdown_column': drop_down_input, 'Float_column': float_input}
      df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
      button.description = 'Add row to dataframe'

      out.clear_output()  # <---

      display(df)
```

---

You can see more about `out.clear_output()` in documentation:
[Output widgets: leveraging Jupyter’s display system](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html#Output-widgets:-leveraging-Jupyter%27s-display-system)